# I am trying to use'IF' and 'OR' function to have values in new column

Tags: python-3.x

```
bu['Order_2']=" "

if ((bu['New_status']=='?') | (bu['New_status']=="Not Sold")):




 bu['Order_2']=" "





else :
    bu['Order_2'] = bu['Type_Designation'].values
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

You can't use pure dataframe as condition. But pandas dataframes have nice `.empty` mehtod for cases like this. :P

```
df_with_needed_data = df.loc[(bu['New_status'] == "?") | (df['New_status'] == "Not Sold")]
    if df_with_needed_data.empty:
        some actions if df is empty
    else:
        some actions if df is not empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. There is a simpler solution to your problem.
You can simply use .loc operator to run a condition over each row and update accordingly. I tried this for your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

Cars = {'Order_2': ["Honda Civic","Toyota Corolla","Ford Focus","Kia Seltos","Audi A4"],
        'New_status': ["Not Sold","Sold","Sold","?","Sold"],
        'Type_Designation': ["A", "B", "C", "D","E"]
    }

bu = pd.DataFrame(Cars, columns= ['Order_2', 'New_status', 'Type_Designation'])
# without any changes
print (bu)

bu['Order_2']=" "
bu.loc[(bu['New_status'] != "?") & (bu['New_status'] != "Not Sold"),'Order_2'] = bu.Type_Designation

# post update
print (bu)
```